# counting runs in a list, how?

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x, while-loop, nested

```
def run_counter():
    #list1 = generate_integer_list(num_int, low_range, high_range)
    list1 = [6, 12, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    run = 0
    for i in range(len(list1) - 2):
        while i < len(list1) - 1 and list1[i] == list1[i+1] - 1:
            run = i + 1
            i += 1
    return run, i - run+1
```

A run is a consecutive order of numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4. 10, 11, 12, etc. For those who don't know.

I'm trying to create a function that returns the length of the first run it encounters in a list, and the index where the run started.

The code I have above, doesn't really do the job. It should return, length of 2, start at 2, but returns length of 7 and start at 1. Any thoughts?

Comment: Tthe comment in my function is what I'm going to use to generate a list, right now I am using a predefined list for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> def runCounter(L):
...   answer = []
...   start = 0
...   end = 1
...   while end < len(L):
...     if L[end] < L[end-1]:
...       answer.append(end-start)
...       start, end = end, end+1
...     end += 1
...   answer.append(end-start)
...   return answer
... 
>>> L = [6, 12, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> runCounter(L)
[2, 2, 4]
```